# protection for duplicate sed replacements

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

This is more of a architectural question:

I have a script that does some in file sed replacements/additions like:

```
sed -i 's/MY_VAR = 1000/MY_VAR = 1000\nMY_VAR2 = 500/' file.txt
```

which works fine but this is part of a fairly large script and someone may either `^C` the first run and re-run this or just re-run it N-times back-to-back which will result in something like

```
MY_VAR = 1000
MY_VAR2 = 500
MY_VAR2 = 500
MY_VAR2 = 500
MY_VAR2 = 500
...
```

which might not be expected. So  my question is: what's the best way to avoid this? I came up with something like:

```
if [ ! -f file.txt~copy ]
then
    cp file.txt file.txt~copy
    sed -i 's/MY_VAR = 1000/MY_VAR = 1000\nMY_VAR2 = 500/' file.txt
fi
```

which should work fine but I was wondering if there's a better/recommended way to go about it? The above could obviously be problematic if your files are significantly large and you may just want to `touch` a copy file for protection instead.

Comment: If you're worried about this not being idempotent then perhaps you could write your changes to a different file than the source, leaving the source untouched. Another option might be to have a guard (or token) in the changed file - if the guard exists then the file has already been modified

Answer (score 2):

This will not easily scale and hence may or may not be a good fit for your real use case, but you may check whether the line you are going to add is already there and only add it if it is not:

```bsh
sed '
  /^MY_VAR = 1000$/ {
    $ b a
    N
    /\nMY_VAR2 = 500$/! s/\n/&MY_VAR2 = 500\
/
    b
    :a a \
MY_VAR2 = 500
  }'
```

Here, when the exact line `MY_VAR = 1000` is found:

- if it is the last (`$`) line, we `b`ranch to the `a` label and `a`ppend `MY_VAR2 = 500` at the end of the output;
- if the pattern space, after appending the `N`ext line to it, does not (`!`) end in a newline followed by `MY_VAR2 = 500`, its embedded newline is replaced with a newline + `MY_VAR2 = 500` + a newline; (we then `b`ranch to the end of the script to avoid running the append command too);
- otherwise, we do nothing.

Comment: Wow, this is some crazy stuff, for me anyways! Thanks! :D